# Ruby metaprogramming: cannot send a method to a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For example I have following custom class and module:

```
module SimpleModule
  def hello_world
    puts 'i am a SimpleModule method'
  end

  def self.class_hello_world
    puts 'i am a SimpleModule class method'
  end
end

class SimpleClass
  def hello_world
    puts 'i am SimpleClass method'
  end

  def self.class_hello_world
    puts 'i am a SimpleClass class method'
  end
end
```

I tried to called those methods inside class and module by using method `send`

```
SimpleClass.send(class_hello_world)  # work
SimpleClass.new.send(hello_world)    # work
SimpleModule.send(class_hello_world) # work
SimpleModule.new.send(hello_world)   # not work
SimpleModule.send(hello_world)       # not work
```

In other word, I don't know how to invoke `hello_world` from `SimpleModule`. It is possible if that method is defined with self before.

I need to do this because I want to implement a "custom-include": that include all methods from module to another class.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: `SimpleModule.new.send(hello_world)` won't work because you just can't have an instance of a module.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida thanks. So Ruby implement keyword "include" by its language or I can do a similar things by using metaprogramming ? If metaprogramming possible, should have a way for call method from module.

Answer (score 5):

**The five statements**

Let's consider those five statements one at a time (but in a different order than as presented). Note that `send`'s argument must be the name of the method expressed as a string or symbol.

```
SimpleModule.send("class_hello_world")
  # i am a SimpleModule class method
```

This is normal, though such methods are normally called *module methods*. Some common built-in modules, such as [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Math.html), contain module methods only.

```
SimpleClass.send(:class_hello_world)
  # i am a SimpleClass class method
```

Since a class is a module, the behaviour is the same as above. `class_hello_world` is usually referred to as a *class method*.

```
SimpleClass.new.send(:hello_world)
  # i am SimpleClass method
```

This is the normal invocation of an instance method.

```
SimpleModule.send("hello_world")
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `hello_world' for SimpleModule:Module
```

There is no module method `hello_world`.

```
SimpleModule.new.send(hello_world)
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for SimpleModule:Module
```

One cannot create an instance of a module.

**`include` vs `prepend`**

Suppose one wrote

```
SimpleClass.include SimpleModule
  #=> SimpleClass
SimpleClass.new.hello_world
  # i am SimpleClass method
```

so `SimpleClass`' original method `hello_world` is not overwritten by the module's method by the same name. Consider `SimpleClass`' ancestors.

```
SimpleClass.ancestors
  #=> [SimpleClass, SimpleModule, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Ruby will look for `hello_world` in `SimpleClass`--and find it--before considering `SimpleModule`.

One can, however, use [Module#prepend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) to put `SimpleModule#hello_world` before `SimpleClass#hello_world`.

```
SimpleClass.prepend SimpleModule
  #=> SimpleClass
SimpleClass.new.hello_world
  # i am a SimpleModule method
SimpleClass.ancestors
  #=> [SimpleModule, SimpleClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

**Binding unbound methods**

There is one other thing you do. `SimpleModule`'s instance methods (here just one) are unbound. You could use [UnboundMethod#bind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) to bind each to an instance of `SimpleClass` and then execute it using `call` or `send`.

```
sc = SimpleClass.new
  #=> #<SimpleClass:0x007fcbc2046010> 
um = SimpleModule.instance_method(:hello_world)
  #=> #<UnboundMethod: SimpleModule#hello_world> 
bm = um.bind(sc)
  #=> #<Method: SimpleModule#hello_world> 
bm.call
  #=> i am a SimpleModule method
sc.send(:hello_world)
  #=> i am a SimpleModule method
```

Comment: thanks. I understand the problem I have met now is because I cannot initialize a module. I tried to proof-of-concept about implement again Ruby keyword **include**. So if I cannot call method on module like this, can I do by some way ?

Comment: thanks for **prepend** keyword. I don't know this before :D but anyway, they still little like **include** in term of language-based keyword. ( so I cannot implement this on my own) :D

Comment: Didn't know about `prepend`, I could see that causing a lot of headaches if it was misused :D. Thanks for the writeup!

Comment: "I could see how ___ could cause a lot of headaches if it were misused." Ruby--any programming language--provides many, many ways to fill in that blank.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039474/ruby-metaprogramming-how-can-make-module-method-see-classs-variable/42045992?noredirect=1#comment71272550_42045992) as how to implement custom include/extend. I have learnt many thing from this post :D

Answer (score 2):

Module's can't have instance methods because they aren't classes.  If you define an instance method in a module it is called a mixin.  These "mixins" can be included in another class and are then available for use.

The full explanation is here in the [docs](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)

Edit:

For example, you could do something like this:

```
module SimpleModule
  def hello_world
    p 'hello world'
  end
end

class Example
  include SimpleModule
end
```

`Example.new.send(:hello_world)`

This is one way to call the mixin of a module.

Comment: thanks. I know "include" keyword. Can I implement "include" on my own ? no real world application, just I want to demonstrate concept but I stuck at call method from module. thanks

Comment: I added an example of how you could include the module in a class and then call send on the class to invoke the module method.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to want to create your own version of include.

Take a look at `Module.append_features` documentation

> When this module is included in another, Ruby calls append_features in
>   this module, passing it the receiving module in mod. Ruby's default
>   implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables
>   of this module to mod if this module has not already been added to mod
>   or one of its ancestors. See also Module#include.

So this is what you have to do if you want to rewrite `include` yourself.

And since you're adventurous, maybe you will enjoy reading Ruby's source code to see how exactly this is implemented internally. See [https://github.com/ruby/ruby...class.c#L853:L934](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/54a77d2044148bb442340f93747e1f345b6ca401/class.c#L853:L934)

Comment: Thanks for linking to source code. it's great. About append, I see I looks like "include", just a little different in behavior compare to include. So I don't think using append is a way for rewrite include :D

Comment: about link to source code. How can you find this ? Are you a contributor of Ruby? I am just little curious. So I can know how can I do same thing in the future. thanks

Comment: I use `pry` and `pry-docs` gem to locate source code, the `$` command shows the source code. And then dig further using search at https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `constantize`:

```
def call_method(method)
  "SimpleModule::#{method}".constantize
end
```